# How to sort column in decreasing ORDER, and if we found a tied record we sort them depending on another column in SQL?

Tags: sql, database

I have 2 separate TABLES one of them is "**movies**" and has a *title* and *id* columns and the other one is "**ratings**" and has a *rating* and *movie_id* column

I want to write a SQL query to list all movies and their ratings, in descending order by rating. For movies with the same rating, order them alphabetically by title.

I used this code but I did not know how to order the tied columns.

```
SELECT title, rating
FROM movies
JOIN ratings
ON movies.id = ratings.movie_id
ORDER BY rating DESC;
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Add your title column also in `order by` clause

```
SELECT title, rating
FROM movies
JOIN ratings
ON movies.id = ratings.movie_id
ORDER BY rating DESC,title asc
```